# Default listing images aren't served from CDN, fail to load because of certificate error

Tags: bug, status-completed

The default images used on the app/script/library pages aren't pointing to the CDN, so their use of HTTPS causes a certificate error that prevents the image from loading:

[image: library default image]

Could the image sources be updated to point to the CDN?

Comment: Confirmed.  The images (now) point to `https://sstatic.net/stackapps/img/script-thumb.png`, for example, which has an SSL cert valid only for `*.stackexchange.com`.  HOWEVER, all the non-default images use `http://` and [`http://sstatic.net/stackapps/img/script-thumb.png`](http://sstatic.net/stackapps/img/script-thumb.png) loads just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fixed now - sorry for the delay!